# Cost weighted java cache

Tags: java, performance, caching

I would like a caching library that manages based on cost weights.

I have a lot of different types of data with exact same structure to cache, but it the costs differ to cache each of different types, some are very cheap to retrieve back, some are expensive.

I want a way where I can add a weight to the caching library such it can efficiently cache to minimise cache misses.

Comment: more info on what kind of data you want to cache may result in a more informed answer

Comment: As you said, the costs differ per type. I have seen this request typically with the idea to put all different data into a single cache. If you separate the different types into separate caches, you can set the cache sizes separately. Is is possible to separate into different caches? How many different types of data you have?

Comment: A latency-aware cache policy would have more cache misses but reduce the overall system latency. Unfortunately there is not a lot of research on this topic. The simplest approach is to use a cache per type and dynamically balance the space allocated, e.g.see [RobinHood](https://blog.acolyer.org/2018/10/26/robinhood-tail-latency-aware-caching-dynamic-reallocation-from-cache-rich-to-cache-poor/).

Comment: I have very large float arrays that are calculated based on genetic algos as it mutates, sometimes it recomputes same structured nodes based on fitness. Now, depending on the complexity computation can take a long time. this is where a cost based cache is useful. Some of these nodes may never get visited and others may get visited several times. some of these structures are not known upfront, and no point of caching each - unless we have infinite amount of RAM. So, what I require is a cache that takes in object ref and cost value, and provides cost optimised java cache.I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You won't find anything out-of-the-box. You might instead use a standard in-memory cache and local storage as if infinite RAM, e.g. load/compute on a miss and persist on eviction. It may be possible to do it all using a memory-mapped file to let the O.S. decide for you. Otherwise, see projects like h2 and mapdb for simple storage options.

Comment: The purpose of cache is to save on costs, that would have occurred had the cache not existed. All cache libraries assume constant cost for cache misses. But in real world costs of cache misses are not constant. Having a cache that maximizes on cost saving would be ideal. Cost saving should be a weighted function of cache hit frequency and and cost for each miss.

Answer (score 0):

[Ehcache 2](https://www.ehcache.org/) had [`Policy`](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.4/net/sf/ehcache/store/Policy.html).

Associate a weight to each value, make it implement your own interface, for example `Weightable`, and use:

```
public class WeightPolicy extends AbstractPolicy {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Weight";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean compare(Element element1, Element element2) {
        return ((Weightable) element1.getObjectValue()).getWeight() < ((Weightable) element2.getObjectValue()).getWeight();
    }
}
```

If the key and value are `Serializable`, you could use [`getSerializedSize()`](https://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10.4/net/sf/ehcache/Element.html#getSerializedSize()), although very inefficient.

```
return element1.getSerializedSize() < element2.getSerializedSize();
```